# Shallow Rendering Jest Testing with Material UI withStyles Component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui

I am writing a test for a component that is wrapped in a withStyles() from Material UI using Jest. I need to test the children elements, but my wrapper is undefined.

I've seen another post similar to writing tests with withStyles(), but the undefined error still persists.

Test File:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

import { TempComponent } from '../../../../src/components/helpers/temp';

describe('temp', () => {
  let wrapper;

  const renderComponent = () => shallow(<TempComponent />);

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = renderComponent();
  });

  it('render correctly', () => {
    expect(wrapper.type()).toEqual('div');
  });
});
```

Component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const TempComponent = () => <button>Click Me!</button>;

export default withStyles({})(TempComponent);
```

I get this error for my test:

Invariant Violation: ReactShallowRenderer render(): Shallow rendering works only with custom components, but the provided element type was `undefined`.

I am wanting the wrapper component to behave the same way as a wrapper without the withStyles() component. Any help would be appreciated!

Note: I am not doing snapchat testing with jest

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the issue and solution:

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9266#issuecomment-349447137

> The issue isn't about the children elements but with the intermediary
>   element, it's creating. The `shallow()` API of enzyme only render one
>   level depth. Any higher-order component is going to obfuscate the
>   children. You have different workarounds. I would encourage you to
>   refer to the enzyme documentation. Still, here they are:
>
> - use `mount()`
> - use `.dive()`
> - use our [createShallow() public API](https://material-ui.com/guides/testing/#api)
> - use our internal `until()` helper